# Binding a command doesn`t work

Tags: wpf, binding, command

I'm beginner in WPF development.
I create some window with frame inside.
I wrote a template for the frame and i`m trying to bind to the buttons inside the freame template commands without success.

see the next code:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Frame" x:Key="NavigationButtonsTemplates">
                <DockPanel>
                    <StackPanel 
            Margin="7"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            >
                        <Button 
                Content="Back" 
                Command="{x:Static NavigationCommands.BrowseBack}"  
                Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="80" />

                        <Button 
                Content="Next" 
                Command="{Binding Path=NavigateToPersonalDataCommand}"
                Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="80"></Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Border 
            BorderBrush="LightBlue"
            Margin="7,8,9,0"
            BorderThickness="7"
            Padding="5"
            CornerRadius="7"
            Background="White"
            >
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
```

It seems that the binding of the buttons is not working.
When i put the buttons outside the tag  it`s work perfectly.
How can I bind a command to a button which located in ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ControlTemplate` needs to have a `DataContext`. Try changing the `DockPanel` element to bind to the `DataContext` property on the templated frame. This assumes that the `Frame` that is being templated has a valid `DataContext`.

```
<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
```

or

```
<DockPanel DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}">
```

**Edit:**

After trying to run your code I found the problem. The properties you are binding to in XAML do not match the properties on your view model.

Changing your XAML to bind to the property names on your view model fixes the problem.

From this:

```
Command="{Binding Path=NavigateNext}"
Command="{Binding Path=NavigateToPersonalData}"
```

To this:

```
Command="{Binding Path=BrowseNext}"
Command="{Binding Path=NavigateToPersonalDataCommand}"
```

to match your view model properties:

```
public ICommand BrowseNext
{
    get
    {
        return m_BrowseNext;
    }
    set
    {
        m_BrowseNext = value;
    }
}

public ICommand NavigateToPersonalDataCommand
{
    get
    {
        return m_PersonalDataCommand;
    }
    set
    {
        m_PersonalDataCommand = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working, I have tried the two options. The buttons are not execute any command.

Comment: @CharlieGrinvald Can you post the code that you have which uses the template? I need more information.

Comment: Thanks! i don`t believe that I didn`t see it before.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Xaml code:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProj"
    x:Class="TestProj.MainView"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainView"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:NavigationViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Frame" x:Key="NavigationButtonsTemplates">
                <DockPanel DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}">
                    <StackPanel 
            Margin="7"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            >
              <Button 
                Content="Back" 
                Command="{Binding Path=NavigateNext}"
                Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="80" />

                        <Button 
                Content="Next" 
                Command="{Binding Path=NavigateToPersonalData}"

                Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="80"></Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Border 
            BorderBrush="LightBlue"
            Margin="7,8,9,0"
            BorderThickness="7"
            Padding="5"
            CornerRadius="7"
            Background="White"
            >
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Button Content="Opening" Grid.Row="0"></Button>
            <Button Content="Personal Data" Grid.Row="1"></Button>
        <Button Content="Business Data" Grid.Row="2"> </Button>
        <Button Content="Summery Report" Grid.Row="3"></Button>

        <DockPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="4">
            <Frame x:Name="mainFrame" Template="{StaticResource NavigationButtonsTemplates}"/>

        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here how i wrote the commands:

```
class NavigationViewModel
    {
        private ICommand m_BrowseNext;
        public ICommand BrowseNext
        {
            get
            {
                return m_BrowseNext;
            }
            set
            {
                m_BrowseNext = value;
            }
        }

        private ICommand m_PersonalDataCommand;
        public ICommand NavigateToPersonalDataCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return m_PersonalDataCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                m_PersonalDataCommand = value;
            }
        }

        public NavigationViewModel()
        {
            BrowseNext = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(NavigateNext));
            NavigateToPersonalDataCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(NavigateToPersonalData));
        }


        public void NavigateToPersonalData(object obj)
        {
            MainView.Instance.GetMainFrame.Navigate(Pages.Opening.Instance);
        }

        public void NavigateNext(object obj)
        {
            MainView.Instance.GetMainFrame.Navigate(Pages.PersonalData.Instance);
        }
   }
```

When i move the buttons outside the  the commands works great so i think the problem is in the XAML.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I updated my answer to address the problem. In the future, you should add updates to your question to the actual question rather than posting it as an answer.